# How to Solve [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] Error when Using urllib without bypassing SSL verification

Tags: python, ssl, urllib

```
import urllib.request
import json
    
gojson = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?osmtype=W&osmid=17025436&class=highway&addressdetails=1&hierarchy=0&group_hierarchy=1&format=json&polygon_geojson=1'
res_body = urllib.request.urlopen(gojson).read()
```

The error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)>
```

I know I can get around the error by using this code:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

But I'd rather know how to solve the issue. I was unable to find solutions when searching the web. Any advice?

Comment: The error suggests it has to do with an expired certificate. When I visit that URL in my browser it shows their certificate expiring next month. Is your system date perhaps set incorrectly?

Comment: @Blckknght I don't believe so, I have not altered any dates in my system.

Comment: I suspect this is the Let Encrypt R3 expiration problem. The solution is to update the root certificates on your system.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I am running on the most recent version of Windows and Windows claims that it automatically keeps root certificates up to date, does this change your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on an Ubuntu machine then:

```
sudo apt install ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
```

If you are on Mac or need to handle it in some other way, refer to following answer:

[urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

Answer (score 1):

One route, would be to pass `urllib.request.urlopen()` the optional "*cafile*" argument with the full path to a trusted CA bundle like a "cacert.pem" file generated by **certifi**.  This can be done with `certifi.where()` from the **certifi** package.

Example, using your code snippet:

```
import certifi  #added import
import json
import urllib.request


gojson = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?osmtype=W&osmid=17025436&class=highway&addressdetails=1&hierarchy=0&group_hierarchy=1&format=json&polygon_geojson=1'
res_body = urllib.request.urlopen(gojson, cafile=certifi.where()).read() #modified function call to add cafile argument
```

Of course, you can use whatever file or path you want, I just provided the example above as it would be require less exploring on the local file system and seems to be relatively trustworthy for a minimum amount of work.  It's generally a more secure practice to use a verified/trusted CA bundle over turning off ssl validation, this was a good question.

My environment:
macOS Big Sur,
Python 3.9

References:

1. [Python package for providing Mozilla's CA Bundle.] https://pypi.org/project/certifi/
2. [package repository] https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi
3. [function details] https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/urllib.request.html?highlight=urlopen#urllib.request.urlopen
4. [certificate authority] https://www.ssl.com/faqs/what-is-a-certificate-authority/